# py.test console output in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest

Jenkins console output from jobs running py.test tests contains unexpected characters "[1m" "[0m" like

```
[1m============== test session starts ==============[0m
```

Apparently these characters are leftovers from py.test output formatting ("test session starts" shows up as bold and colored in a terminal window). Is there a way to disable the output formatting? py.test's "--color no" option is not enough.

Comment: As a side note, we use [ANSI Color Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) and get nicely colored output from `pytest` in Jenkins console.

Comment: I've installed the plugin however I'm still not able to see any colors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

In my case I'm running the pytest inside a docker by suing Jenkins descriptive pipeline, so need to verify several things:

First, add `ansiColor` to the `options`

```
pipeline {
...
    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Second, verify that you added the `docker run` command the flag `-t`

> -t              : Allocate a pseudo-tty

for docker-compose it's `tty: true`

Third, you can  force colorize by adding `--color=yes` to the pytest command 
`python -m pytest --color=yes ...`

> --color=color         color terminal output (yes/no/auto).

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the [AnsiColor](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) plugin in Jenkins. In its configuration panel there will be a new item "Ansi Color" with a xterm color map

   2. Your pipeline should contain something like:

      ```
      stage('Pytest'){
        wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'xterm']) {
            sh """
            source ./$PYTHON3_ENV_NAME/bin/activate

            # Execute tests
            python3 -m pytest test_cases/${TEST_FILTER} --color=yes ....
            """
        }
      }
      ```
   3. During run you should see then colors for pytest stage.
      If you see the bash color formatting but not the colors, press F5 on browser!

Riccardo